# Converting code written with delay to millis() instead

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I have a basic code I wrote on Arduino, however, I need to change the delay to Millis instead.

Whatever I do I can't get it to work, it's always getting stuck at a red light and won't ever turn green.

I'm posting the original delay code as code I wrote using Millis seems useless and may confuse what I'm trying to do.

```
const int redPin = 2;
const int yellowPin = 3;
const int greenPin = 4;

int redDuration = 10000;
int greenDuration = 5000;

void setup() {
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellowPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  setTrafficLight(1,0,0);
  delay(redDuration);
  setTrafficLight(1,1,0);
  delay(2000);
  setTrafficLight(0,0,1);
  delay(greenDuration);
  setTrafficLight(0,1,0);
  delay(2000);
}

void setTrafficLight(int redState, int yellowState, int greenState) {
  digitalWrite(redPin, redState);
  digitalWrite(yellowPin, yellowState);
  digitalWrite(greenPin, greenState);
}
```

Comment: You can see the code I wrote using Millis here: https://codeshare.io/5Z4B4g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Save the time when it started waiting.
2. If the difference of current time and the start time become the time to wait, proceed to the next status.

```
const int redPin = 2;
const int yellowPin = 3;
const int greenPin = 4;

int redDuration = 10000;
int greenDuration = 5000;

unsigned long startTime;
int status = 0; // using enum may be better

void setup() {
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellowPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  startTime = millis();
  status = 0;
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();
  switch (status) {
    case 0: // initial state
      setTrafficLight(1, 0, 0);
      status = 1;
      break;
    case 1: // waiting instead of delay(redDuration)
      if (currentTime - startTime >= redDuration) {
        setTrafficLight(1, 1, 0);
        startTime = currentTime;
        status = 2;
      }
      break;
    case 2: // waiting instead of first delay(2000)
      if (currentTime - startTime >= 2000) {
        setTrafficLight(0, 0, 1);
        startTime = currentTime;
        status = 3;
      }
      break;
    case 3: // waiting instead if delay(greenDuration)
      if (currentTime - startTime >= greenDuration) {
        setTrafficLight(0, 1, 0);
        startTime = currentTime;
        status = 4;
      }
      break;
    case 4: // waiting instead of second delay(2000)
      if (currentTime - startTime >= 2000) {
        startTime = currentTime;
        status = 0;
      }
      break;
    default: // for in-case safety
      status = 0;
      break;
  }
}

void setTrafficLight(int redState, int yellowState, int greenState) {
  digitalWrite(redPin, redState);
  digitalWrite(yellowPin, yellowState);
  digitalWrite(greenPin, greenState);
}
```

Comment: works perfect, there were two errors that I noticed which were easy to fix Thank you so much.